# Pub/Sub Lite GRPC - Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: 502:Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, grpc, publish-subscribe

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Pub/Sub Lite service in NodeJS using grpc. However, I am stuck with the following error : {"code":14,"details":"502:Bad Gateway","metadata":{"internalRepr":{},"options":{}}} when I try to publish a message in the queue.

I can't manage to make it works, can anyone help ?

Here is my code:

```js
    async function message() {

const protoDir = "node_modules/google-proto-files/google/cloud/pubsublite/v1/publisher.proto";
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(protoDir, {
  includeDirs: [
    protos.getProtoPath('..'), 
    'node_modules/google-proto-files/google/cloud/pubsublite/v1/'
  ],
  keepCase: true,
     longs: String,
     enums: String,
     defaults: true,
     oneofs: true
});

const packageObject = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
const package = packageObject.google.cloud.pubsublite.v1;
const Publisher = package.PublisherService

var ssl_creds = grpc.credentials.createSsl();
const gAuth = new GoogleAuth({
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
});
  gAuth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, auth) {
    var call_creds = grpc.credentials.createFromGoogleCredential(auth);
    var combined_creds = grpc.credentials.combineChannelCredentials(ssl_creds, call_creds);
    const client = new Publisher('europe-west1-pubsublite.googleapis.com', combined_creds)

    const initial = {
        topic:'projects/projectId/locations/europe-west1-b/topics/poc-topic',
    }

    var pub = {
        request_type: initial
    }
    const pubb = client.Publish(function(err, res) {
      console.log("ERROR --> " + err)

    });
    
    pubb.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Data --> " + data);
    });
    pubb.on('end', function() {
      console.log('end ')
    });
    pubb.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('Error ' + e)
    });
    pubb.on('status', function(status) {
      console.log('Status ' + JSON.stringify(status))
      pubb.write(pub);
    });
    
  });
}
```